# How to capture a video of specified window in Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, screen-capture

I have tried to capture a screen video using this sample code
[How to capture screen activity to a movie file using AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1740/_index.html)

It's working fine but I am wondering how can I capture a specified window of some individual app (not screen area specified by CGRect).

I'm asking because Google Hangouts can share specified window even if it isn't visible. 
[image: Google Hangouts]

So, my questions are:

1. How can I modify the code above to achieve this?
2. Is it possible to capture few windows at the same time?

Comment: You don't show any code, so what are you asking how to modify?

Comment: I have posted the link with code sample.

Comment: It's Apple's code, not your's?

Comment: Yes, it is. I said I want to modify it to capture a separate window, not full screen.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it? Some screen recording apps offer this option but I cannot find any way to to it.

Comment: @LembergSun, I'm very curious to know if this has been solved. Do you have an update on it?

Comment: @Sean256 No, unfortunately I couldn't find any solution. And I'm not working on this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible to capture video of background window using `AVFoundation`, unless you make your own concrete subclass of `AVCaptureInput`. But taking screenshot of background window can be implemented using [CGWindowListCreateImage()](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) function from `Core Graphics` framework. Apple's [SonOfGrab](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code may be helpful.